# Integration Testing Spring boot application JSON Assert

Tags: java

I have spring boot application was trying to write Integration testing but when i ht the in memory DB i get one value from that but when do ASSERT TO MATCH THE PARAMETER VALUES i AM  NOT ABLE TO COMPARE THE SIZE AND VALUES

these how the response when i hit the api in Postman

```
{
    "continuationToken": "09/07/19 05:21 PM",
    "permit": [
        {
            "expiry": null,
            "activation": "2019-07-01T06:00:00.000+0000",
            "permitId": "C8S43N5",
            "plateNumber": "ERT1234",
            "plateState": "AB"
        },
        {
            "expiry": null,
            "activation": "2018-12-17T22:04:13.947+0000",
            "permitId": "CGW3TNF",
            "plateNumber": "FDF",
            "plateState": "AB"
        }
  ]
}
```

```
        Assert.assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), Matchers.equalTo(HttpStatus.OK));
        String jsonBody = response.getBody();
        Assert.assertThat(jsonBody, JsonPathMatchers.hasJsonPath("$[0].expiry", Matchers.equalTo("2080-06-26T06:00:00.000+0000")));
        Assert.assertThat(jsonBody, JsonPathMatchers.hasJsonPath("$[0].activation", Matchers.equalTo("2019-06-26T22:33:14.849+0000")));
        Assert.assertThat(jsonBody, JsonPathMatchers.hasJsonPath("$[0].permitId", Matchers.equalTo("CS383UA")));
        Assert.assertThat(jsonBody, JsonPathMatchers.hasJsonPath("$[0].plateNumber", Matchers.equalTo("VGZ05")));
        Assert.assertThat(jsonBody, JsonPathMatchers.hasJsonPath("$[0].plateState", Matchers.equalTo("AB")));
```

> java.lang.AssertionError:  Expected: is json with json path
>   "$[0]['expiry']" evaluated to "2080-06-26T06:00:00.000+0000"
>        but: json path "$[0]['expiry']" was not found in <{continuationToken=09/07/19 05:31 PM,
>   permit=[{"expiry":"2080-06-26T06:00:00.000+0000","activation":"2019-06-26T22:33:14.849+0000","permitId":"CS383UA","plateNumber":"VGZ05","plateState":"AB"}]}>

Comment: use `$.permit[0].expiry`, etc.

Comment: @DanielM Thanks how to get the Size  Assert.assertThat(jsonBody,JsonPathMatchers.hasJsonPath("$",Matchers.hasSize(1)));

Comment: That's a different question, not sure which size you want to check - but I believe something similar `Assert.assertThat(jsonBody,JsonPathMatchers.hasJsonPath("$.permit",Matchers.hasSize(1)));`

Comment: use `$.permit.length()` to get size of permit array

Answer (score 1):

The array is under `permit` key, so change your code

```
       Assert.assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), Matchers.equalTo(HttpStatus.OK));
        String jsonBody = response.getBody();
        Assert.assertThat(jsonBody, JsonPathMatchers.hasJsonPath("$.permit[0].expiry", Matchers.equalTo("2080-06-26T06:00:00.000+0000")));
        Assert.assertThat(jsonBody, JsonPathMatchers.hasJsonPath("$.permit[0].activation", Matchers.equalTo("2019-06-26T22:33:14.849+0000")));
        Assert.assertThat(jsonBody, JsonPathMatchers.hasJsonPath("$.permit[0].permitId", Matchers.equalTo("CS383UA")));
        Assert.assertThat(jsonBody, JsonPathMatchers.hasJsonPath("$.permit[0].plateNumber", Matchers.equalTo("VGZ05")));
        Assert.assertThat(jsonBody, JsonPathMatchers.hasJsonPath("$.permit[0].plateState", Matchers.equalTo("AB")));
```